# Using a custom TeX .fmt file is Emacs/Auctex

Tags: auctex

I am attempting to use a plain TeX format, say, `foo.fmt` (which is findable with `kpsewhich`), with
Emacs/AUCTeX (actually Aquamacs with built-in AUCTeX). I'm unable to
get AUCTeX to recognize the custom format. In TeXShop (a Mac TeX
frontend) I would simply say at the top of the file:

```
% !TS-program=foo
```

In Emacs, I have tried various "Local Variables" such as

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-engine: foo
%%% End:
```

followed by <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd>. <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> returns an error indicating that the `.fmt` file has not been used. What am I missing?

Comment: Cross post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427001/31416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this without your foo.fmt file, but I think you need to set this using the variable `TeX-command-extra-options`:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "--fmt=foo"
%%% End:
```

I'm not sure of the syntax, maybe it should be `--fmt=foo.fmt` instead.

Comment: The format should indeed be `-fmt=foo.fmt`. That worked perfectly. Thanks!